# How to get release apk using gitlab? CI CD

Tags: android, git, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

**NB:** I new in  gitlab CI CD
Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
assembleRelease job: stage parameter should be .pre
build
test
deploy
.post
```

You can also test your .gitlab-ci.yml in CI Lint

My .gitlab-ci.yml code

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:   ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "29"   ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "29.0.2" ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "4333796"

before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
  - unzip -d android-sdk-linux android-sdk.zip
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" >/dev/null
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" >/dev/null
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./gradlew   # temporarily disable checking for EPIPE error and use yes to accept all licenses
  - set +o pipefail
  - yes | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
  - set -o pipefail

lintDebug:   stage: build   script:
    - ./gradlew -Pci --console=plain :app:lintDebug -PbuildDir=lint

assembleDebug:   stage: build   script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug   artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/

debugTests:   stage: test   script:
    - ./gradlew -Pci --console=plain :app:testDebug

assembleRelease:
    stage: release   script:
  - echo $KEYSTORE_FILE | base64 -d > my.keystore
  - ./gradlew assembleRelease
    -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=$(pwd)/my.keystore
    -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password=$KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
    -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=$KEY_ALIAS
    -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=$KEY_PASSWORD   artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/apk/release
    - CHANGELOG
```

**NB:** Please share pipeline build test and release cd code for android

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm too late, but our .gitlab-ci.yml format is wrong. You missed several new lines.
For example, in `assembleRelease` after the `stage: release` you need a new line, `script:` should be on a new line

Answer (score 0):

1. the ident in .yaml file is important. You have mixed 2 spaces and 4 spaces indent. you should make them same. normally it should be 2 spaces.
2. the stage, script, and artifact should be in a new line, not in same line.

here is a possible fix

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "28"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "28.0.3"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS:   "6609375_latest"

before_script:
  - echo ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK ${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
  - echo ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS ${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}
  - echo ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS ${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
  - unzip -d android-sdk-linux android-sdk.zip
  - export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export SDK_MANAGER="${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}"
  - echo y | ${SDK_MANAGER} "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
  - echo y | ${SDK_MANAGER} "platform-tools" >/dev/null
  - echo y | ${SDK_MANAGER} "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" >/dev/null
  - export PATH=$PATH:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  # temporarily disable checking for EPIPE error and use yes to accept all licenses
  - set +o pipefail
  - echo y | ${SDK_MANAGER} --licenses
  - set -o pipefail

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release

lintDebug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew -Pci --console=plain :app:lintDebug -PbuildDir=lint

assembleDebug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/

debugTests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew -Pci --console=plain :app:testDebug

assembleRelease:
  stage: release
  script:
    - echo $KEYSTORE_FILE | base64 -d > my.keystore
    - ./gradlew assembleRelease
      -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=$(pwd)/my.keystore
      -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password=$KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
      -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=$KEY_ALIAS
      -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=$KEY_PASSWORD
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/apk/release
      - CHANGELOG
```